# Функция get_post_meta() в WordPress не работает

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Использую CMS WordPress, версия 4.7.2.

Имеется произвольное поле с `$key=price` и некоторым значением. Задачи вывести поле в определенном месте страницы. Мой код:

`<p><?php $page_id =the_ID();  get_post_meta($page_id, 'price', true);?>aaakv</p>`

`page_id` выводит, а собственно значение производного поля нет. Пробовал варианты с `get_metadata()` и тоже не помогло. Подскажите, будьте добры, в чем может быть проблема. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_ID()` выводит ID текущего поста **НА ЭКРАН**.

Надо так:

```
<?php
  $page_id = get_the_ID();
  $meta = get_post_meta($page_id, 'price', true);
  echo $meta;
?>
```

Comment: Да, заработало! Благодарю!

Comment: Точно! А я и не обратил внимание как получает $page_id - всё внимание get_post_meta :)

Comment: так бывает...... )

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так надо:

```
<?php 
$page_id = the_ID();
$key_price_values = get_post_meta($page_id, 'price', true);
echo  $key_price_values;
?>
```

Comment: Попробовал, опять выводит id страницы(

Comment: ID быть не может. Его функция принимает, а не отдаёт. Возможно где-то ошибка в синтаксисе или названиях переменных/полей.